# Store string into array from length of character

Tags: php, arrays, string, separator

What i actually want to do is:

i.e

```
$str="abcdefghijklmnopqrst";
```

Now i want to store characters from string which are strats from number 2 to 5.

I have try following :-

```
<?php
$string_name='abcdefghijklmnopqrst';
print_r(str_split($string_name));
echo '<br>';
print_r(str_split($string_name,4));
echo '<br>';
?>
```

but this will make array with 4 characters.
And i have no separator so i have only way to separate word is from length.

Comment: _strats_ ??? `substr()` maybe?

Comment: Wait, can you show an example of the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
$str = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
echo substr($str, 1, 4); // where 1 starts b and ends at f
```